# Javascript error log says function not defined when I have defined it in a separate file and even the same file

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

This is the smallest simplest start I could think of, and of course it errors. I'm running a .cshtml page. Here is the code for having function in the SAME file just lines apart:

```
@section head
{
    <script>
        function CheckPostalCode(form) {
            if (form.postalcode.value.length < 5) {
                alert("Please enter a Zip Code.");
                form.postalcode.focus();
                return false;

            }

            return (true);
        }
    </script>
}
```

Now in the webpage below:

```
<form onsubmit="return CheckPostalCode(this)" method="post" action="/search/index.cshtml">
    <input type="text" name="postalcode" id="postalcode" size="30" maxlength="5" required/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="go" />

</form>
```

The original method I tried to use was having a separte file called checkFields.js and including the file in the pages section head as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/checkFields.js"></script>
```

Where the webpage code is the same. Can anyone help explain why even when the script is in the same file its undefined. But really I would like to be able to call the function from another file. I've seen many tutorials that all say, you can call functions like normal so long as you include them. Well I thought I did.

When viewing page source it's simply the form with a header tag above it

Comment: are you sure the file is being loaded? Check the network tab on you browser.

Comment: Also check your console for errors. There probably is one.

Comment: Well the console error is how I even figured out it was saying CheckPostalCode() is undefined. But @Phil I'm not sure what you mean check the network tab i'll look at that now

Comment: When launching page I see index.cshtml with method get. Then when I click go function crashes and the network shows the search/index page. So nothing appearing for the js file

Comment: can you check and share how ur html page source after rendering ?

Comment: I think because the page source doesn't have anything a page needs It's probably a "layout" issue. Where the layout would have everything like <!DOCTYP html> and <head>  who knows.

Comment: Do you use `@RenderSection("head")` somewhere?

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev I see that in another project from a website that has it in its layout file. So I guess I know that I need to specify a layout.

Comment: well, the problem is you don't have the `.js` file... I think you need to close this question and figure out how to include files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using @section head to include some raw javascript from your view, you need a RenderSection("head", false) in your _Layout.cshtml file ("head" is a name defined by yourself, you can change it to other name), in `<head></head>` part, like:

```
<head>
     //your other css link or js link here
     @RenderSection("head", false)
</head>
```

If you use link, try to use "~"

```
<script src="~/js/checkFields.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or use:

```
<script src='@Url.Content("~/js/checkFields.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Who knew it wasn't even a javascript issue. I'll just go ahead and say it. Making a website is hard....

Comment: You can remove additional stuff, only leave raw html and javascript in your page, and check the source code rendered by browser, and check if error still happen. This will simply troubleshooting process. @section is a ASP.NET MVC functionality, not belongs to standard raw html and javascript. Making a website is not that so hard, keep learning, you will get there.